# Fixed slider and the navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem with the nav bar.
When i use [bx-slider](http://bxslider.com/), the nav bar is in the back and I can't click on the links.
The the navbar is behind the slider.
I wish to undestand the problem.

This is my code:

```css
*{margin: 0;padding: 0;}
/* Start Navigation Bar */
.mainNav{
    height: 0;
}
.mainNav .logo{
    float: left;
}
.mainNav .myUl{
    float: right;
    z-index:99;
}
.mainNav .items{
    display: inline-block;
    /*margin: 30px 30PX 0 30PX;*/
    font-size: 20px;
}
/* End Navigation Bar */
/* -------------------------- */
/* Start Header */
.mainHeader{
    background-image: url('../images/1.jpg');
}
.mainHeader .bx-wrapper{
    height: 100%;
    z-index:1;
}
.mainHeader .bx-wrapper .bx-viewport{
    height: 100% !important;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: 0;
    background: none;
    z-index:1;
}
/* End Header */
```

```html
  <body>
<!-- Start Navigation Bar -->
<nav class="mainNav">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="logo">Hello Otaku</h2>
    <ul class="myUl">
      <li class="items"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- End Navigation Bar -->
<!-- Start Header -->
<div class="mainHeader">
  <ul class="bxslider">
    <li><h3>Hello World</h3><br/><p>HAHAHAHAHAHAHHAHAHAHAHHA</p></li>
    <li><h3>Hello World</h3><br/><p>HAHAHAHAHAHAHHAHAHAHAHHA</p></li>
    <li><h3>Hello World</h3><br/><p>HAHAHAHAHAHAHHAHAHAHAHHA</p></li>
    <li><h3>Hello World</h3><br/><p>HAHAHAHAHAHAHHAHAHAHAHHA</p></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example, [here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Did you try giving `.mainNav{z-index:99999;}`

Comment: Your question is not clear :(.

Comment: my question is when i use a slider the navigation bar be behind the slider ans i can't click in links of navigation

Comment: @REVERSI, that's still not a question. What have you tried to resolve the problem yourself?

Comment: Capitalized title